# Unable to update dataflow: "You must enable row-level sharing on the connected dataset..."

Tags: einstein-analytics, dataflow

I've created a dataflow that uses an `sfdcDigest` to grab records from Account, ProcessInstance, and ProcessInstanceStep, two `augment` steps to join them all together, and finally an `sfdcRegister` to conclude the dataflow.

In the `sfdcRegister` node I've set *Sharing Source* to ["Account"] to leverage Salesforce sharing within the dataset.

When I click "Update Dataflow", I receive the following error and am unable to start the dataflow.

> WARNING: Your dataflow definition contains errors that will cause your dataflow to fail. You must enable row-level sharing on the connected dataset for the Account object before you can use row-level sharing in this dataflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix for the error is simple, but searching for the error message itself was not helpful. The issue was two settings:

- First, **Inherit sharing from Salesforce** needs to be enabled. This can be found under Setup > Analytics > Settings.
- Second, there is a step needed for every object you want to use sharing for.

1. Open Tableau CRM Studio
2. Click **Data Manager**
3. In Data Manager, click **Connect**.
4. Find the object you want to modify and in the rightmost column will be a dropdown list (in my case this was *Account*). Click **Row Level Sharing**.
5. Set **Sharing inheritance on**.
6. Click **Save**.